# spring-cloud-sleuth-error-posting-spans-to-zipkin server

Tags: spring-bean, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have zipkin server running and when i hit the zipkin client rest api end point i am getting the error below

2017-06-10 23:16:08.782  INFO [product,d650504f4f922a51,d650504f4f922a51,true] 5676 --- [ix-ProductAPI-3] com.accenture.api.ProductAPI             : List all Product
Hibernate: select product0_.prod_id as prod_id1_0_, product0_.prod_description as prod_des2_0_ from product product0_
2017-06-10 23:16:09.801  WARN [product,,,] 5676 --- [ender@698c7814)] z.r.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter   : Dropped 1 spans due to HttpClientErrorException(404 null)

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:590) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin.RestTemplateSender.post(RestTemplateSender.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin.RestTemplateSender.sendSpans(RestTemplateSender.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:228) [zipkin-reporter-0.6.12.jar:na]
    at zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$Builder.lambda$build$0(AsyncReporter.java:153) [zipkin-reporter-0.6.12.jar:na]
    at zipkin.reporter.AsyncReporter$Builder$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source) [zipkin-reporter-0.6.12.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

Comment: At what IP and port is your zipkin server running and what are your properties. It hurt can't reach zipkin...

Comment: [Project Code](https://github.com/bharathmit/SpringCloud-MSA).   
Zipkin server: spring:
  application:
    name: monitoring
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8080
server:
  port: 9411

Comment: What has config to do with zipkin? You have to point to a zipkin collector.

Comment: Thanks Marcin helping them... I found the solution after add the dependency in pom.xml                                                     
                   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
      <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: hey it s possible to add hystrix monitor to zipkin server application?

Comment: I guess it will work but i wonder if it's a good idea to mix the two